# Receiver not registered from DialogFragment

Tags: android, dialogfragment, receiver

I tried to creating wifi manager from Dialogfragment.However, I can not pass a problem that Receiver not registered.

```
 private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
```

Then, I'm creating a method is that:

```
 @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

   setRetainInstance(true);


   //gets Wifi instances

   mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
   //wifi state control
   if (!mWifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Wifi enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
   }
   //register BroadCast


   getActivity().getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent ıntent) {
     mScanResults = mWifiManager.getScanResults();
     size = mScanResults.size();
     Log.d("WiFi", "Total Wifi NetWork ======= > " + size);
    }
   }, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));

   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    /*  checkandAskPermission();*/
   } else {


    mWifiManager.startScan();
    values.clear();

    try {
     size = size - 1;
     while (size >= 0) {
      device d = new device();
      d.setName(mScanResults.get(size).SSID.toString());
      d.setBssIdName(mScanResults.get(size).BSSID.toString());
      values.add(d);
      mWifiScanAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      size = size - 1;
     }
    } catch (Exception e) {
     Log.d("Wifi", "Wifi-------------->" + e.getMessage());
    }
    btnScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {

      mWifiManager.startScan();
      values.clear();
      try {
       size = size - 1;
       while (size >= 0) {
        device d = new device();
        d.setName(mScanResults.get(size).SSID.toString());
        d.setBssIdName(mScanResults.get(size).BSSID.toString());
        values.add(d);
        mWifiScanAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        size = size - 1;
       }
      } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.d("Wifi", e.getMessage());
      }
     }
    });

   }
 }
```

then It's the issue here when the device rotates, DiolagFragment restarts and I clicked the button again or not state save that can check to Wi-Fi state again and I clicked the button again too.not good but not too bad, later
I used this method:

```
 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
```

I get the error that Receiver not registered.
or I'm setting setRetainInstance(true) in onCreateView after I deleted setRetainInstance(true) from onActivityCreated method.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wifisdialog, container, false);
  setRetainInstance(true);

  btnScan = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.wifiScan);


  mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.adam_wifi_recycle);
  mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


  mWifiScanAdapter = new WifiScanAdapter(values, getContext());
  mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mWifiScanAdapter);

  this.getDialog().setTitle("Wifi Manager");


  return view;
 }
```

then I have set the unregisterReceiver as you can see:

```
 @Override
        public void onDestroyView() {
            super.onDestroyView();
            getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        }
```

I still get the error that Receiver not registered.

And, in MainActivity is:

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.welcome_page);
            new WifiCheck().execute();
    }

 public class WifiCheck extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(HomePageLRG.this);

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

                new WifiDialogFragment().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Wifi Manager");

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

                pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
                pdLoading.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                pdLoading.dismiss();
            }
        }
```

Okay, That's run perfectly when I click the button, I get all the Wifi features the way I want.Exactly in the local area.
But I want to that: 
if the dialog box is open and show wifi in the local area then device rotates, not changing
or 
if the dialog box (dialogfragment, whatever you say) is not open then device rotates, not changing.

I think it is that possible but I can not found, Can someone help me? 
and I'm sorry for my bad english.

Comment: why don't you check if your Receiver is registered with a Boolean flag or just use SavedInstanceState  to determine device rotation.

Comment: @MehranZamani, thanks for the answer but How can do that? I edit `private boolean flag =true` then I added in onReceive from onActivityCreated method and called `flag=false`. Later I called that flag=true in onDestroy() method.But the problem still continues.

Comment: see `isVCRregistered` flag in [my code](https://github.com/Kickass86/MPAS/blob/master/app/src/main/java/turbotec/mpas/SplashActivity.java). Pay attention where did i set it true/false.